# usb to rs232 data transmission in python

Tags: windows

serial.serialutil.SerialException: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31) i am getting this error please help me

before i already write code for 4 ports(usb) in stm32cubeide i got output luke usb to rs232 and usb to can now i am checking in python more data is transmitting or not (usb to rs232) but while debugging its telling this error serial.s erialutil.Serial Exception: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: Permission Error(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31)